# Returning a value from a function is not working

Tags: javascript, function, return

please dont mark this question as duplicate. I know there is a similar question, just cant understand how to do it exactly so i need a non detailed explanation-solution. I'm having a function which is designed to return the local ip address. The function is this:

```
const clientsIpAdress = (onNewIP) => {
  const MyPeerConnection =
    window.RTCPeerConnection ||
    window.mozRTCPeerConnection ||
    window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
  const pc = new MyPeerConnection({
    iceServers: []
  });
  const noop = () => {};
  const localIPs = {};
  const ipRegex =
    /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g;

  const iterateIP = (ip) => {
    if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
    localIPs[ip] = true;
  };
  pc.createDataChannel('');
  pc.createOffer().then((sdp) => {
    sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach((line) => {
      if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
      line.match(ipRegex).forEach(iterateIP);
    });

    pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
  });
  pc.onicecandidate = (ice) => {
    if (!ice || !ice.candidate ||
      !ice.candidate.candidate ||
      !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
    ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(iterateIP);
  };
};
export default clientsIpAdress;
```

The i have an object which contains the ip_adress as a parameter:
My object is this:
obj : { name: "Alex", lastname: "Markus", ip_adress: the local ip address}
It seems like this function is asynchronous so i cant return a value just simple so i'm writing obj: {name: "Alex", lastName: "Markus", clientsIpAddress(ip => ip_adress: ip)} But it is not working. Please help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Is it so difficult to assign a value via an asynchronous function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is syntactically impossible. You'll have to do sth. like this:

```
let obj = {name:"Alex", lastName: "Markus"};
clientsIpAdress(newIP => { obj.ip_address = newIP });
```

Your code that makes use of the `obj` object still has to be aware of the fact that the `ip_address` property may not be set, yet, when it tries to use it. You have to take into account that the property is set at a later point in time.

Comment: Wait, i have a function: export function* login(username, password, locale) {
  const requestParams = {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Accept-Language': locale,
      device_type: device,
      os: operatingSystem,
      display: screen,
    },
    method: 'post',
    body: `username=${username}&password=${password}`
  }; and the i wrote clientsIpAdress((newIP) => { requestParams.headers.ip_address = newIP; }); The ip_adress is not in my object when i debug it

Answer (score 0):

```
export function* login(username, password, locale) {
  const requestParams = {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Accept-Language': locale,
      device_type: device,
      os: operatingSystem,
      display: screen
    },
    method: 'post',
    body: `username=${username}&password=${password}`
  };
clientsIpAdress((newIP) => { requestParams.headers.ip_address = newIP; });
```

Still it's now working. Should i assign an ip_address property to the headers?